# Set Nautilus to stop browsing into a folder upon a drag-and-drop

Tags: nautilus

When I drag-and-drop a file into a folder, Nautilus will browse into the folder. Can this behaviour be stopped? I prefer to change folders only when I explicitly make the change.

Comment: What version of nautilus (or Ubuntu) & what view. Gnome finally realized the mistake of having this in **icon view** (canvas) & put it in as an option. However you'd only see this as an option in 16.10 or 17.04's nautilus, not in 16.04 where it has to be patched out.

Comment: I'm using 16.04.

Comment: If desired I can point you to a patch I have for this, you'd need to rebuild nautilus yourself. Otherwise have a nautilus ppa that includes this along with other patches to improve nautilus (from my pov..)  Let me know.

Comment: @doug, Re improvements: I've always thought the contrast in the "path" is very poor. It's hard to see which is the currently open folder. Of course it's the rightmost normally but when you browse to parents the contrast is poor. Just a thought.

Comment: Well that ^ may be theme.. Anyway read here & if deciding to use make sure to upgrade all your nautilus source packages (usually at least 3). Patches are described & at page bottom the ones used in 16.04 are listed. https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/nauty-hacks1